# Regular expressions: how to use 'or' without more capturing groups?

Tags: python, regex, expression, capturing-group

We are supposed to only add the regular expression to a script without touching anything else. The script is made so that it accepts 3 capturing groups and there are 2 different regular expressions on which depends the output. I prepared the epxressions for both cases, but when I do:

```
expression1 | expression2
```

The script thinks that there are 6 capturing groups (each expression containing 3 capturing groups) and therefore gives me an error.

How should I join the 2 expressions without the script thinking that there are 6 capturing groups, because both expressions can never be applied, it is either expression1 or expression2, but never both at the same time.

The expressions1 is:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ]?)\(P[: ]?([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)()
```

The expressions2 is:

```
()()\)[ ]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+$|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ])
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Is the regex library used `re` or `regex`?

Comment: The only library for the script is 're'

Comment: There is no generic solution for `re`. Saeko, please post the actual patterns.

Comment: I don't know if the exclusive-or logic can be concisely and expressively written in Python regular expression. Sounds like altering the logic of the code would be more straightforward.

Comment: The expressions1 is: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ]?)\(P[: ]?([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)()

The expressions2 is: ()()\)[ ]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+$|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ])

Comment: @Saeko, can you update your post with the expressions please.

Comment: @Cong Ma Unfortunately, it is for a school project and when I edit something else in the script expect for the regular expression and try to upload it, the school system doesn't accept it because the file is edited in places where it is not supposed to be edited

Comment: How does this school system work? Did they actually ask you to create such regex? Seems so pointless. If not, what is so special about this line so that it's the only one allowed to be edited?

Comment: This is for the course named 'Scripting language', we were supposed to start with basics of Python, but instead started with Regex... which wouldn't be that bad, but this projects seems to focus on making the regular expressions as difficult as humanly possible. We got a full script with few dots that needed to be replaced by the regular expressions and we can check whether our script works on their website, which also checks whether the script has been edited in any way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: after post update, because group 1 and 2 are empty in second expression and group 3 is empty in first, they should be combined with a non-capturing group and just by removing empty groups :

```
(?:([a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ]?)\(P[: ]?([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)|\)[ ]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+$|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ]))
```

Also the last group `([a-zA-Z0-9]+$|[a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ])` can be shortened

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:$|[ ]))
```

Non-capturing groups `(?:` .. `)` may be used instead of `(` .. `)`, to group pattern without adding new group.

without more information about expression1 and expression2 it's difficult to answer suppose the patterns have following form:

```
exp1: (g11)s11(g21)s21(g31)
exp2: (g12)s12(g22)s22(g32)
```

the combined expression can be

```
(?=(?:g11)s11(?:g21)s21(?:g31)|(?:g12)s12(?:g22)s22(?:g32))((?:g11|g12))(?:s11|s12)((?:g21|g22))(?:s21|s22)((?:g31|g32))
```

but it may be simplified depending on what is required.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 normal alternatives and few bad:

First normal. separate via code:

```
if (expression1) {
    DO SOMETHING
} else if (expression2) {
    DO SOMETHING
} else {
    NO MATCH FOR BOTH
}
```

Second normal. Work with all 6 pockets.

```
if (arMatches[1] or arMatches[2] or arMatches[3]) {
    DO SOMETHING
} else if (arMatches[4] or arMatches[5] or arMatches[6]) {
    DO SOMETHING
} else {
    NO MATCH FOR BOTH
}
```

For bad solutions you can use very complex regex, that will probably have some hidden mistakes and this experssion will be VERY hard to maintain, probably not possible at all.